# Maven custom Archetype generator Sources and Resources missing

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, m2e, maven-archetype

We are developing modular application where we want to use common template for each ERP module. Created own `archetype` inspired by `maven`. Finally we are able to deployed it own `repository` as usually able to generate project by own archetype.

1. Where is we  have to register lots files into `archetype.xml`, this is the break point for me. Because we are not interested to register lots of files into `archetype.xml` manually as it is time consuming matter.
2. `archetype.xml` file where I could register `sources`, `resources`, `testSources`, `testResources`. In this situation How do i could register another custom directory?
3. Although `archetype-metadata.xml` we registered `fileSets` and `requiredProperties` but no effect on generating project.

After deployed into maven repository archetype jar file inspected by me. and all the sources resources and custom directory found on jar entry. but with out registering them `archetype.xml` we are unable to get them inside generated project. In this situation our expected solution as following:

1. Sort command/regex to copy/generate all the sources and resources
2. Sort command/regex to copy/generate all the content of custom directory
3. or `archetype.xml` auto generator for specific directory/sources/resources

Comment: Is this a 1.x or 2.x archetype? The 'archetype:create' command is deprecated and creates a 1.x version, while 'archetype:create-from-project' creates a 2.x version.  If you use 'archetype:generate' and choose the maven-archetype-archetype, this is also a 1.x version that is deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new to maven `archetype`. do not worry. I would like to suggest you to create your `archetype` from existing maven project which one standard for `archetype` template. delete unnecessary files and folders. Just go to your project directory by cli. just run following command:

```
your-maven-project>mvn archetype:create-from-project
your-maven-project>cd target\generated-sources\archetype
...urces\archetype>mvn clean deploy
```

do not feel doubt about `mvn archetype:create-from-project` actually its the magic command to generate archetype. you may customize generated archetype as your demand by googling. Now generate project by your own `archetype`

```
...urces\archetype>cd your-workspace-dir
your-workspace-dir>mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=<archetypeGroupId> -DarchetypeArtifactId=<archetypeArtifactId> -DarchetypeVersion=<archetypeVersion>
```

That's all. enjoy your own `archetype`.